# Adding multiple sentences after "was advised to"

Tags: passive-voice

What is the most correct :

"He was advised to lose some weight, do regular exercises and quit smoking"

Or

"He was advised to lose some weight, do regular exercises and to quit smoking"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule for this, so it's a matter of style (and preference) more than grammar.

The first sentence is elliptical. The *to* is assumed to apply to each item in the list, even if it's not actually present in front of the second and third items:

> He was advised **to** lose some weight, (to) do regular exercises, and (to) quit smoking.

In this example, the *(to)* does not really exist, it's just what you mentally assume to exist.

It acts the same way as *she ate an apple and (an) orange*, in which the second *an* is optional and often left out.

---

If you apply the *to* explicitly to each item, you end up with this:

> He was advised **to** lose some weight, **to** do regular exercises, and **to** quit smoking.

Sometimes the first version sounds better, and sometimes the second version sounds better. Neither is wrong or more right than the other.

---

However, in versions of a sentence where each item starts with something different, you do have to be explicit in every case:

> He was advised **to** lose weight, **of** how strenuous regular exercises would be, and **against** smoking.

Note that there is also something else that's assumed to exist in front of each item, even though it's still only being written in front of the first: *he was advised*.

A *completely* explicit sentence would look like this:

> He was advised to lose weight, he was advised of how strenuous regular exercise would be, and he was advised against smoking.

---

Typically, either *to* would be applied to only the first item or it would be applied to every item.

In your question, the second version you give is actually a mix of those two forms:

> He was advised **to** lose some weight, (to) do regular exercises, and **to** quit smoking.

The *to* is missing from the second item, but exists in front of both the first and third items.

While also not wrong, it's a nonstandard approach to the sentence. It's not something you would expect to see. Most people don't construct sentences with such a mixed form. When they don't see the *to* in front of the second item, they would just silently assume its presence—but would then be startled to see it explicitly appear again in front of the third item. So, it's not wrong, but it is a bit awkward.